# Assigning people to a position based on their choice and score in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame (df1) like this

```
Position    Available   Minimum
Position 1         3    2
Position 2         1    1
Position 3         7    5
Position 4        12    8
Position 5        24    17
Position 6         7    5
Position 7        18    13
Position 8        10    7
Position 9        25    18
```

And I have another data frame (df2) like this

```
Candidate Choice1    Choice2     Choice3     Choice4      Score 
Name 1   Position 2 Position 4  Position 6  Position 9     62
Name 2   Position 8 Position 2  Position 6  Position 5     70
Name 3   Position 5 Position 4  Position 1  Position 6     42
Name 4   Position 8 Position 9  Position 5  Position 2     20
Name 5   Position 6 Position 1  Position 1  Position 1     6
Name 6   Position 4 Position 7  Position 2  Position 4     7
Name 7   Position 1 Position 3  Position 8  Position 6    56
.            .      .           .           .             .
.            .      .           .           .             .
Name n  Position 6  Position 6  Position 4  Position 5     8
```

Now, I want to assign the candidate to a position based on their score and their choice. If a candidate did not get the choice 1 then we have to look for choice-2 and assign.

Example is given below,

```
Name    Choice1     Choice2      Choice3    Choice4   Score Assigned in
Name 2  Position 2  Position 8  Position 6  Position 5  70  Position 2
Name 1  Position 2  Position 4  Position 6  Position 9  62  Position 4
Name 7  Position 1  Position 3  Position 8  Position 6  56  Position 1
.   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

Conditions:

1. Highest scorer would get the first preference
2. If the preferred order is not available then assign him/her in some available position
3. In df1 we have a column called "Minimum" which is 70% of the total available seats for that particular position. We need to fill out at least these many seats for a position. (We can ignore if total number of candidates are available less than 70% of the total seats available)

I do not know how to start with this logic in R. Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: Why does `Name 2` get assigned in `Position 2`?

Comment: @Khashaa: I made small mistake there in 'choice 1', now I have edited the correct choice. Name2 has the highest score so he gets as he chose (Position 2), Name1 has the second highest and he also chose "Position 2" as his first choice but there is only one vacancy in position 2. So he has been assigned to 'position4' which is his 2nd choice. Thanks for the catch..

Comment: Have you tried @Karsten's suggestion?

Comment: I'm trying.. I'm not good at R. @Karsten's code assigns based on choice1 and I'm not sure how to include other choices in this loop. Also, the current code assigns the positions by ascending (score) order but It needs to be done by descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create assignment and position vectors

```
assignments <- rep(NA, n) # n ... candidates
positions <- rep(0, m) # m ... positions
```

and loop over `df2`, sorted by score (code below is untested):
EDIT: decreasing, example for more than one choice

```
for (i in order(df2[,"Score"], decreasing=TRUE)) {
    choice <- df[i, "Choice1"]
    if(positions[[choice]]<df1[choice, "Available"]) {
        assignments[[i]] <- choice
        positions[[choice]] <- positions[[choice]]+1
        next # move to next candidate
    }
    choice <- df[i, "Choice2"]
    if(positions[[choice]]<df1[choice, "Available"]) {
        assignments[[i]] <- choice
        positions[[choice]] <- positions[[choice]]+1
        next
    }
    # check choice3, ..., choice4, handle case that all choices are
    # not available
}
```

This does not take into account the Minimum requirements, though. For this, it might be a good idea to formulate the problem as a linear optimization problem and solve it with a package like `lpSolve` or `lpSolveAPI`. Here is an formulation attempt (again, untested):

```
# the variable we are interested in
p_ij ... candidate i at position j (0 or 1)

# auxilliary variables that are optimized by the LP
cf_ik ... candidate i choice k was fullfilled (0 or 1)

# pre-set constants
w_k ... weight for choice k (e.g. w_1=4, ..., w_4=1)
prefs_ijk ... candidate i chose position j as his k th choice
highscore_i ... score for candidate i # may need to rescale this or the w_k
min_pj ... minimum seats
max_pj ... maximum seats

# objective function
obj: max sum_i highscore_i * 
     (w_1 * choice_i1 + w_2 * choice_i2 + w_3 * choice_3 + w_4 * choice_4)

subject to:

# make sure all position are appropriately filled
min_pj <= sum_i (pij) <= max_pj for all j

# one position per candidate
sum_j pij == 1 for all i

# link between choices of candidate choice_ik and assignment
cf_ik = sum_j prefs_ijk * p_ij
```

One challenge here is to transform the data frames to the LP, another to interpret the feedback from the LP solver.

Comment: Thanks Karsten, LP part is very advanced for me. However, I will try this. BTW, how to get the assignment as it is instead of number? Currently. it gives the 1,2.... 11. I would like to get "Position 1" or "Position 2".. etc

Comment: Thanks for accepting... Regarding your question, try `paste("Position", assignments)`.

Comment: Above given scenario is for example, I want to bring the position name directly to the assignment with out using the {paste} For example, if I have position called "Chairman" or "General Manager". I need to bring it in the 'assignments'. Thanks !

Comment: Then you could build a map `position_labels <- c("1"="Chairman", "2"="General Manager", <etc>)`, and then use `position_labels[assignments]` to perform the mapping.